# Adding code to child theme functions.php to override parent theme behaviour doesn't work

Tags: php, themes

I am trying to override some behaviour in a parent theme ([Blackoot Lite](https://www.iceablethemes.com/shop/blackoot-lite/)) and used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22995302/overriding-parent-theme-functions-in-wordpress) StackOverflow question as a guide.

My goals are twofold—I want to unregister a default sidebar in the parent theme, plus I want to add a custom header widget area. Neither thing ends up happening.

Below is my code, which I put into the child theme's `functions.php`:

```
<?php

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_parent_styles' );

function enqueue_parent_styles() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
}

function wpb_widgets_init() {

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => 'Custom Header Widget Area',
        'id'            => 'custom-header-widget',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="chw-widget">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="chw-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );

}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wpb_widgets_init' );

function blackoot_lite_unregister_sidebar() {
    unregister_sidebar('sidebar');
    unregister_sidebar('footer-sidebar');
}
add_action( 'after-setup-theme', 'blackoot_lite_unregister_sidebar' );
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: What did you change regarding other template files?

Comment: I didn't make any other changes. All of the googling I did indicated that I only had to add that code to functions.php and that was sufficient. I read a bunch of tutorials, but they were for older versions of Wordpress and had contradictory information.

Comment: Should I be using a filter? I considered that first, but thought maybe it was overkill.

Comment: Well if you want to add a widget area in the header, the you should add code to the header.php also: `if ( is_active_sidebar( 'particular-sidebar' ) )
dynamic_sidebar( 'particular-sidebar' );`
You could also remove the unwanted sidebar by removing these lines. But first you should find these places in the parent theme, copy those files over to your child theme, and change them accordingly.
Also you should check in your parent theme where is the widget added, and remove it according to that. "after-setup-theme" may not be a good 'place'.

Comment: the action `after-setup-theme` doesn't exist in WordPress core. it may be the action `after_setup_theme` ?

Comment: @D.Dan I'm going to see how to give you kudos; I'm still learning my way around here. Regardless of the outcome, you've been very helpful and deserve recognition. 

Comment: @mmm, same goes for you. 

Comment: @D.Dan I created a `sidebar.php` (which is where the sidebars get created in parent) and copied the last five lines from my code block in the original question. That seemed to work. Now I need to implement your suggestion about adding the widget area in `header.php`.

Comment: Basically you need to see with an if statement, if the sidebar is to be used aka. `is_active_sidebar` - and if it is in the { brackets } you should put like a div, or whatever you want around the content of that sidebar, and tell WP to write out the content of that particular sidebar with `dynamic_sidebar`, below is a tutorial with a full example.

Answer (score 0):

You may find [this](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-a-wordpress-widget-to-your-website-header/) useful to understand how to add a widget area in WP.